# В чем отличие Single от Observable в RxJava?

Tags: java, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Друзья! В чем различие Single и Observable? Не понятно, когда использовать Observable вместо Single, во всех обычных операциях получение с БД данных или из сети всегда один запрос, а значит всегда ответ один раз приходит - это, как я понимаю Single, а когда тогда Observable?

Answer (score 1):

Single - исполнится и завершится событием Success или Error.

Observable - будет испускать данные до тех пор, пока не вызовется событие Error или Complete.

Отсюда следует, что для однократного получения данных нужно использовать Single, а для постоянного получения данных из некоторого источника - Observable. Последний, например, можно использовать для получения изменённых данных в к-л таблице в БД.

Также надо учитывать механизм Backpressure - он не реализован в Observable и при испускании источником данных слишком часто он может перестать работать. Если использовать Flowable - эта проблема будет решена один из нескольких способов.

Answer (score 0):

Single не имеет всех методов, которые есть у Observable. Subscriber у Single также отличается тем, что содержит только два метода, а не три. Думаю, что все отличия в плане реализации вы сможете найти в документации.

Single (что можно даже и из названия понять) содержит только один элемент, в отличии от Observable.

Можно ли использовать Observable для с одним элементом? Да можно, но тут необходимо понимать, что Observable более тяжеловесный, чем Single (а поговаривают, что Single даже быстрее);

Если вы знаете, что вы будете работать только с одним элементом, то в использовании Observable нет нужды или, как говорят, overkill

В Single возможны две ситуации:

- одно значение -> onSuccess()
- exception -> onError()

В Observable их 3

- получение следующего значения -> onNext()
- операция завершилась успешно -> onComplete()
- exception -> onError()